# Code Coverage with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I am writing a JUnit test case to for a method and I am also trying to get the code coverage. My existing test should cover the scenario but for some reason it still shows as red in the cobertura report.

Method to be tested.

```
public <T extends BaseServiceResponse> T postProcess(T response,
        ClientResponse clientResponse) throws EISClientException {  

    List<Message> messages = response.getMessages();
    if(messages==null || messages.size()==0) {
        return response;
    }

    Map<String, Message> messagesMap = populateMessages(response.getMessages());
    ConditionOperator condition = getCondition();

    switch(condition) {
        case OR:
            checkORCondition( messagesMap );
            break;
        case AND:
            checkANDCondition( messagesMap );
            break;
    }       
    return response;
}
```

JUnit test case:

```
@Test
public void testPostProcess() throws Exception {
    clientResponse = mock(ClientResponse.class);
    RetrieveBillingServiceResponse response = new RetrieveBillingServiceResponse();

    // Testing OR condition (200 status code)
    MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter postProcessFilter = new MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter();
    postProcessFilter.setCondition(ConditionOperator.OR);

    Message message = new Message();
    message.setMessageCode("200");
    message.setMessageType(MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO);
    message.setMessageText("Service completed successfully");

    response.setMessages(Arrays.asList(message));

    RetrieveBillingServiceResponse serviceResponse = postProcessFilter.postProcess(response, clientResponse);

    assertNotNull(serviceResponse.getMessages());
    assertEquals(1, serviceResponse.getMessages().size());
    assertTrue(serviceResponse instanceof RetrieveBillingServiceResponse);
    assertFalse(serviceResponse.getMessages().isEmpty());
    assertEquals("200", serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageCode());
    assertEquals("Service completed successfully", serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageText());
    assertEquals(MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO, serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageType());     

    // Testing OR condition (404 status code)
    message.setMessageCode("404");
    message.setMessageText("request not found");
    message.setMessageType(MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO);

    response.setMessages(Arrays.asList(message));
    serviceResponse = postProcessFilter.postProcess(response, clientResponse);

    assertNotNull(serviceResponse.getMessages());
    assertFalse(serviceResponse.getMessages().isEmpty());
    assertEquals(1, serviceResponse.getMessages().size());
    assertEquals("404", serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageCode());
    assertEquals("request not found", serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageText());
    assertEquals(MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO, serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageType());     

    /**
     * Testing AND condition
     * Catching EISClientException
     */
    boolean caughtException = false;
    try {
        postProcessFilter.setCondition(ConditionOperator.AND);

        List<String> myMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
        myMessages.add("200");
        myMessages.add("400");

        serviceResponse = postProcessFilter.postProcess(response, clientResponse);

        assertNotNull(serviceResponse.getMessages());
        assertEquals("400", postProcessFilter.getMessageCodes());

    } catch (EISClientException ex) {
        caughtException = true;
        assertEquals("All of the specified message codes matched returned errors.", ex.getMessage());
    }
    assertTrue(caughtException);

    // Null messages
    postProcessFilter.setCondition(ConditionOperator.OR);

    List<Message> myList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    message.setMessageCode(null);

    serviceResponse = postProcessFilter.postProcess(response, clientResponse);

    assertEquals(0, myList.size());
    assertEquals(null, serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageCode());
}
```

I am unable to cover the if statement for message == null || message.size ==0

Any help would highly be appreciated. This should be simple for message not to be null and my existing code should have covered it but I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yousuf,

In order to get into that block of code, you will need at least one of those conditions in the or statement to be true; so let's check both conditions.

Firstly, the response object you are passing into the `postProcess()` method always has a list of messages, which is why the first condition `messages == null` has not been met.

Secondly, your list of messages is not empty (you've added messages as part of your test, and never cleared them) and therefore the second condition `messages.size() == 0` has not been met.

Fix: If you clear all the messages from response, say with `response.setMessages(null)`, it will then enter into that `if` block and the code coverage will recognize it.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. So in future I have to test both scenarios. Thank you so much Brian.